# Persist Entity Framework query cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6.1

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web-application and use EF 6.1 to access my DB.
I have some rather complex LINQ queries which take up to 10s to compile, but then execute in a few milliseconds. EF does cache this queries fine and the second time the query is executed it returns within this few milliseconds.
But this cache is not persisted so on every app-restart the query needs to be recompiled, which takes that 10s again.

*Is there a way to persist this query cache so it survives an app-restart?*

Comment: http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2014/07/09/three-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-first-query-performance/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already do most of this and it does not handle the query cache, but only model caching...

Comment: The query cache is a Dictionary<QueryCacheKey, QueryCacheEntry> inside QueryCacheManager. 
I tried saving it using reflection, but since QueryCacheKey and QueryCacheEntry is not public and not marked as Serializable it is not possible.

Save/load query plan cache would be a very helpful feature to have, so you should create an issue on http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced

Comment: @bmurmistro: I talked to Rowan Miller from the EF team at /build/ last month and with EF 7 this will be either easily possible or already "in the box" so I am waiting for EF 7...

Comment: ChrFin did you solve this? I have the same problem, so desperated... :(

Comment: @Carlos No, not yet. EF Core I can't use as I have TPT and for EF 6 it's still not possible. I'm thinking of doing it on my own when I have some time as EF is Open-Source now, but the "when I have some time"-factor is unpredictable ;-)...

Comment: @Carlos I actually did try this and it's not easily solvable - I might just wait for TPT in EF Core ;-)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use compiled queries: [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
static readonly Func<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>> s_compiledQuery2 = 
CompiledQuery.Compile<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>>(
        (ctx, total) => from order in ctx.SalesOrderHeaders
                        where order.TotalDue >= total
                        select order);
```

But as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx) the query object must not go out of scope. You can handle this by either keeping it cached in the session or as application variable.

Comment: Sorry, but this does NOT help, as during execution of my app they are already cached by EF. I want to store this *persistently* so it survives a app-restart...

Comment: You can compile it during app startup in background so it is ready when u use it. If that's not possible you can serialize the compiled query object to file and restore it from there. Therefore only the very first use is slow. However this can only be done with compiled queries.