# Entity Framework Performance Issues over 500+ entities model

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, load, mapping

I'm having troubles with the high cost on initial data model first load over 500+ tables. I've elaborated a little testing program to evidence this.

For the proof, the database is **AdventureWorks** with 72 tables where the largest table with row count is [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] (121,317 records):

1. On **EF5** without pre-generated views performing a basic query (select * from SalesOrderDetails where condition) the result is: **4.65** seconds.
2. On **EF5** with pre-generated views performing (select * from SalesOrderDetails where condition) the result is: **4.30** seconds.
3. Now, on **EF6** without pre-generated views performing the same query (select * from SalesOrderDetails where condition) the result is: **6.49** seconds.
4. Finally, on **EF6** with pre-generated views performing the same query (select * from SalesOrderDetails where condition) the result is: **4.12** seconds.

The source code has been uploaded in my TFS online at [[https://diegotrujillor.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/EntityFramework-PerformanceTest]](https://diegotrujillor.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/EntityFramework-PerformanceTest), please let me know the user(s) or email(s) to grant all access and proceed to download it to examine. The test was performed on a local server pointing to .\SQLEXPRESS.

So far, we can see some subtle differences and the picture doesn't look very daunting, however, the same scenario in a real prod environment with 538 tables definitely goes in a wrong direction. It is impossible to me to attach the original code and a database backup due to size and privacity stuff (i can send some pictures or even have a conference sharing my desktop to show running live). I've executed hundreds of queries attempting to compare the generated output trace on sql server profiler, and then paste and execute the sentence and the time consumed is 0.00 seconds in sql server editor.

On the live env, **EF5** without pre-generated views it can take up **259.8** seconds in a table with 8049 records and 104 columns executing a very similar query respect to the mentioned above. This goes better with pre-generated views: **21.9** seconds, one more time, the statement generated in sql server profiler takes 0.00 seconds to execute.

Nevertheless, on the live env, **EF6** it can take up **49.3** seconds executing the same query without pre-generated views, with pre-generated: **47.9** seconds. It looks like the pre-generated views doesn't cause any effect in **EF6** or it already have pre-generated views, from core functionality or something else, don't know.

Thus, i had to perform a downgrade to EF5 as mentioned in my recent post [[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx?CommentPosted=true#10561183]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx?CommentPosted=true#10561183).

I've already performed the same tests over database first and code first with same results. Actually i'm using the "Entity Framework Power Tools" add-in to pre-generate views, both projects, the real and testing are in .NET Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2013 is the IDE and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 the DBMS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used a profiler to check what exactly is taking so long? Is only "the first hit" so slow or also repeated hits?

Comment: We solved similar problems previously by migrating from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5; you can find many interesting details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx (`Many of the performance improvements made for Entity Framework 5 reside within the core components that ship with .NET 4.5`). BTW question in current state doesn't fit well for SO, and can be closed as too broad / no specific cases reasons

Comment: @ChrFin Thanks for help, yes i've checked it with profiler and it takes 0.00 seconds. Yes, only "the first hit"

Comment: @Lanorkin Thanks for answer, i'm going to perform my tests on .NET 4.5 and let you know.

Comment: I did not mean if the query takes that long, but what in your code taktes that long using a CLR profiler, but as you already answerd with "only the first hit": This delay is caused by EF compiling the LINQ query to SQL. At subsequenty hits this is cached so it does not take this time again. I am seacrhing a way to persist this cache at the moment too (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073248/persist-entity-framework-query-cache), but for now I only can recommend you to introduce some "warm-up logic" which pre-fills that cache...

Comment: Yes, by the moment i'm working with a splash screen to inject the "warm-up logic".