# Does Entity Framework generate SQL queries every time a call is made to the database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework generate SQL queries every time a call is made to the database? Or is each different query generated at the beginning of the run-time?

If so, what is its performance compared to executing manually built queries?

Comment: Considering queries can be dynamic based on user input if you write your own queries using `System.Linq.Expressions` it is extremely improbable that all possible queries are generated at system startup. Also, why don't you try both methods and see for your self? There may be a difference but is the difference big enough to matter for your use case?

Comment: EF cannot possibly know each and every query at the beginnig of runtime., especially since they can be dynamically generated.  Don't confuse generating queries v.s actually running them.  A complex query can be generated in no time, but could take "forever" to run.  EF-generated queries are generally fine in my experience but when you need to to complex stuff, nothing really beats a well made hand-crafted query.

Comment: Queries are run when you execute a command. Regarding performance, ORMs have overhead and can impact performance.

Comment: The *family* of queries (same query flavor, different values) is often cached, and there is usually a "compiled query" option that moves all the work (except the actual parameter values) to an explicitly accessible / reusable thing....

Comment: These links may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/03/23/entity-framework-query-caching/   https://stackoverflow.com/q/26073248/1236044

Comment: Just run SQL Profiler to see what happens during these events.

Comment: I'm often amazed at how many comments just say "figure it out yourself". Isnt this site about helping each other and not re-inventing the wheel every time?

Whats the matter with listening to other peoples experiences If they have the knowledge. Why spend time doing work that others might want to share.  I think this kind of question differ from "can someone please code this basic stuff for me", since its just about sharing knowledge, not about learning by experience.